# CardLayout : How to get an event to start only when a particular card is displayed?

Tags: java, swing, timer, cardlayout

I am using CardLayout to display a series of questions. For each question, there is a timer displayed on a label. I pass the questions and the time limit for each question from the main class.

```
//Reference - SynforgeTutorials
public class Quiz extends JFrame{
    JPanel p=new JPanel();
    CardLayout cards=new CardLayout();
    int numQs;


    int cardnumber;

    CL1 questions[];



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] messages = {"What is area of a circle?","When does spring start?","When is the next leap year?","How many days in a week?","What causes seasons?"};
        int[] mins = {1,2,0,1,1};
        int[] secs = {30,0,30,0,0};
        new Quiz(messages,mins,secs);
    } 

    public Quiz(String messages[],int mins[],int secs[]){


        questions = new CL1[messages.length];

        for(int i=0;i<questions.length;i++)
        {
        questions[i] = new CL1(messages[i],mins[i],secs[i],this);

        }

        p.setLayout(cards);

        numQs=questions.length;
        for(int i=0;i<numQs;i++){
            p.add(questions[i],"q"+i);
        }

        cardnumber = 0;

        cards.show(p,"q"+ cardnumber);


        add(p);
        setVisible(true);


    }

    public void OK(){
        if(cardnumber==(numQs-1)){

            this.dispose();

        }
        else{

            cardnumber = cardnumber + 1;
            cards.show(p,"q"+ cardnumber);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the class that constructs the cards. It has 3 panels - the top panel where the question is displayed, the center panel where the Minutes and Seconds are displayed on a label along with a Pause and Resume button, and the bottom panel where the OK button is present. On clicking the 'OK' button, the next card is displayed.

```
public class CL1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    int correctAns;

    Quiz quiz;
    int selected;
    boolean used;

    private Timer myTimer1;
    public long initialTimeInSecs;
    public long elapsedTime;
    public long convertToSecs;
    public String minutes;
    public String seconds;
    public String clockTimeString; 
    public static final int ONE_SEC = 1000;
    Font myClockFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20);




    //Message
    JPanel qPanel=new JPanel();

    //Timer
    JPanel tPanel=new JPanel();
    JLabel timeLbl = new JLabel("New label");
    JButton btnPause=new JButton("Pause");
    JButton btnResume=new JButton("Resume");


    //bottom
    JPanel botPanel=new JPanel();
    JButton OK=new JButton("OK");



    public CL1(String q, int userMinutes, int userSeconds, Quiz quiz){

        this.quiz=quiz;

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


        //Message
        qPanel.add(new JLabel(q));
        add(qPanel);


        //Timer
        convertToSecs = (userMinutes * 60) + userSeconds;

        initialTimeInSecs = convertToSecs;
        elapsedTime = initialTimeInSecs;

        seconds = Integer.toString((int)(elapsedTime % 60));
        minutes = Integer.toString((int)((elapsedTime % 3600) / 60));
        if (seconds.length() < 2)
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        if (minutes.length() < 2)
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        clockTimeString = (minutes+":"+seconds).toString();

        timeLbl.setText(clockTimeString);
        timeLbl.setFont(myClockFont);
        timeLbl.setBorder(raisedbevel);

        myTimer1 = new Timer(ONE_SEC,new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                initialTimeInSecs = initialTimeInSecs - 1;

                elapsedTime = initialTimeInSecs;

                String seconds = Integer.toString((int)(elapsedTime % 60));
                String minutes = Integer.toString((int)((elapsedTime % 3600) / 60));


                if (seconds.length() < 2)
                    seconds = "0" + seconds;

                if (minutes.length() < 2)
                    minutes = "0" + minutes;

                clockTimeString = (minutes+":"+seconds).toString();

                timeLbl.setText(clockTimeString);

                if(clockTimeString.equals("00:00"))
                {
                    myTimer1.stop();

                }
                } 

          });

        myTimer1.start(); 



        btnPause.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {   
                PauseBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });



        btnResume.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {   
                ResumeBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        tPanel.add(timeLbl);
        tPanel.add(btnPause);
        tPanel.add(btnResume);

        add(tPanel);


        //bottom

        OK.addActionListener(this);

        botPanel.add(OK);

        add(botPanel);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object src=e.getSource();
        //OK button
        if(src.equals(OK)){

            quiz.OK();}

    }

    public void PauseBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        myTimer1.stop();
    }

    public void ResumeBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        myTimer1.start();
    }
}
```

The timer doesn't seem to refresh with every new card. It starts parallely for every card, so that when I go from one card to the next, the new card shows the time already elapsed on the first card.

For eg, For question 1 , time limit is 1.30 For question 2 , time limit is 2.00 For question 3 , time limit is 3.00

The dialog box first shows the first label and starts ticking down from 1.30. Say I stayed on this label for 10 secs before pressing 'OK'.

Then the second label is displayed and the timer starts ticking down from 1.50 ( 2.00-0.10, instead of 2.00 ). Say I stay on this question for 25 secs before pressing 'OK'.

Then the third label is displayed and the timer starts ticking down from 2.25 ( 3.00-(0.10+0.25), instead of 3.00 ).

I want to do 2 things :

1. I want the timer for each card to start only when that card is shown.
2. I want the card to automatically change to the next card once the time limit reaches 00:00.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want the timer for each card to start only when that card is shown.

You can use a `HierarchyListener` to listen for changes in the visibility of each card:

```
@Override
public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e)
{
    JComponent component = (JComponent)e.getSource();

    if ((HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED & e.getChangeFlags()) != 0
    &&  component.isShowing())
    {
        // start the Timer
    }
}
```

So you would need to add the `HierarchyListener` to each panel you add to the `CardLayout`.

> I want the card to automatically change to the next card

`CardLayout` support "next card" functionality, so you just invoke the appropriate method when the Timer reaches 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I was able to start the timers individually for every card. Regarding the second part, how can I change to the next card once the timer reaches 0? The cards are being changed from the container class, where as the timer is present in one of the panels in the called class.

Comment: @sanaku, Read the `CardLayout` API. It supports "next" card functionality, so you just invoke the `next(...)` method.